# Sorting symbols in 'List of Symbols'

Tags: symbols, lists, sorting

Is there a way I can sort the symbols (in some logical order) automatically in my LaTeX draft? Presently they come in the order I am defining them.

```
\clearpage % Start a new page
\lhead{\emph{Symbols}} % Set the left side page header to "Symbols"
\listofnomenclature{lll} % Include a list of Symbols (a two column table)
{
$y$ & State variable\\
$\mathbb{R}$ & Real space\\
$\bf{x}$ & Vector of training indipandent variables\\
${\mathbf{x}'}$  & Vector of testing indipandent variables
}
```

[image]

Comment: don't use `\bf`. it's deprecated. also check the answer in this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348640/how-to-effectively-use-list-of-symbols-for-a-thesis

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can get an automatically sorted list, but not with what the template provides. Have a look at package acro or glossaries-extra.