# Creating nomenclature with Symbol, Description Unit and different seperations

Tags: symbols, description, nomenclature, units

Hi fellows from the StackExchange Community,
I am currently writing my bachelor thesis in Latex (Overleaf) and got into some trouble while creating my nomenclature.
Since I found that one of my professors  has used a pretty good looking nomenclature in his dissertation I tried to implement the same style into my thesis (I already asked him to help me but unluckily he has written it in word). Due to forum research I was already able to create a nomenclature with the 3 columns und seperations between different kind of symbols, but the lines above and under the symbol lines are driving me crazy. Can somebody help me out?

[image: This is how his style looked]

[image: and he also used seperation for the Latin and Greek symbols]

thanks both of you for your fast answer. My bad, I should posted earlier what I accomplished so far.

I want to have the possibility to maybe write a text between the nomenclature chapter and the first entry of the nomenclature and of course the lines above and under the seperated sections

Here is the code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,siunitx}

\usepackage{nomencl}\makenomenclature
% % % % % % % % %% Nomgroup setting: Starting% % % % % % % % %
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
\newcommand*{\chSubtitle}[1]{\item[\large\bfseries#1]}
\newcommand*{\DescrWidth}[1]{\parbox[c]{7cm}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\chUnit}[1]{\hfill\makebox[1.7cm]{#1\hfill}}

\newcommand*{\chnomSeq}[1]{\csname chSymb#1\endcsname}
\renewcommand*{\nomgroup}{\chnomSeq}

%=====================================================
%==============Defining Greek Symbols=================
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\chSymbG}{\chSubtitle{Greek Symbols}%
\item [\textbf{Symbol}]%
\textbf{Description}\chUnit{\textbf{Unit}}}
%=====================================================
%===========Defining Roman Symbols====================
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\chSymbR}{\vspace{5mm}\chSubtitle{Roman Symbols}%
\item[\textbf{Symbol}]%
\textbf{Description}\chUnit{\textbf{Unit}}}
%=====================================================
%===========Defining Other Symbols====================
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\chSymbO}{\vspace{5mm}\chSubtitle{Other Symbols}%
\item[\textbf{Symbol}]%
\textbf{Description}\chUnit{\textbf{Unit}}}
%=====================================================
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\chwithUnit}[4]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
{\DescrWidth{#3}\chUnit{#4}}}

\newcommand*{\nmG}[4][]{\chwithUnit{G#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand*{\nmR}[4][]{\chwithUnit{R#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand*{\nmO}[4][]{\chwithUnit{O#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

\title{Nomenclature adjustments}
\author{Malte Grube}

% % % % % % % % % % Nomgroup setting: Ending % % % % % % %
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nmR[E]{$e_b$}{Bilayer elastic curvature energy density}{\si{J/m^2}}
\nmG[O]{$\omega$}{Angular velocity}{\si{rad/sec}}
\nmG[A]{$\theta$}{Angular displacement}{\si{rad}}
\nmR[R]{$R$}{Circle radius}{\si{m}}
\nmR[B]{$B_i$}{Biot number}{-}
\nmO[L]{$L$}{Characteristics length}{\si{m}}
\printnomenclature[3.5cm]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You say that you have already managed to write the table, so please post here a full [minimal working example](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) of what you have done so far, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Then we can take it from there.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447253/134144 contains some useful examples (especially the last one) that look pretty similar to the screenshot in your question.

Comment: @leandriis Yeah the last one looks exactly like what I want but I don't know how to combine that one with my predefined nomenclature sections

Comment: @MalteGrube I suggest to use nomencl package: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all your hints. I think I figured it out know, but i dont know if it is a good way to do it.

If you think there is a better way let me know.

So my final Solution looks like

[image: Nomenclature]

and here is my corresponding Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{nomencl}\makenomenclature

% % % % % % % % %% Nomgroup setting: Starting % % % % % % % % %
%\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{Today we write a preamble\markboth{\nomname{}}{\nomname}}
\newcommand*{\chSubtitle}[1]{\item[\large\bfseries#1]}
\newcommand*{\DescrWidth}[1]{\parbox[c]{7cm}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\chUnit}[1]{\hfill\makebox[6em][l]{#1 \hfill}\ignorespaces}

\newcommand*{\chnomSeq}[1]{\csname chSymb#1\endcsname}
\renewcommand*{\nomgroup}{\chnomSeq}

%Table Design
\newcommand{\Answer}[1]{\smash{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X l} \hline #1 \\ \hline \end{tabularx}\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}}

%=====================================================
%==============Defining Greek Symbols=================
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\chSymbG}{\chSubtitle{\Answer{Greek Symbols}}%
\vspace{5mm}\item [\textbf{Symbol}]%
\textbf{Beschreibung}\chUnit{\textbf{Einheit}}}
%=====================================================
%===========Defining Roman Symbols====================
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\chSymbR}{\chSubtitle{\Answer{Roman Symbols}}%
\vspace{5mm}\item[\textbf{Symbol}]%
\textbf{Description}\chUnit{\textbf{Einheit}}}
%=====================================================
%===========Defining Other Symbols====================
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\chSymbO}{\chSubtitle{\Answer{Other Symbols}}%
\vspace{5mm}\item[\textbf{Symbol}]%
\textbf{Beschreibung}\chUnit{\textbf{Einheit}}}
%=====================================================
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\chwithUnit}[4]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
{\DescrWidth{#3}\chUnit{#4}}}

\newcommand*{\nmG}[4][]{\chwithUnit{G#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand*{\nmR}[4][]{\chwithUnit{R#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand*{\nmO}[4][]{\chwithUnit{O#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}


\title{Nomenclature adjustments}
\author{Malte Grube}


% % % % % % % % % % Nomgroup setting: Ending % % % % % % %
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%=====================================================
%===================Roman Symbols ====================
%=====================================================
\nmR[E]{$e_b$}{Bilayer elastic curvature energy density}{J/m$^2$}
\nmR[RE]{$\theta$}{Angular displacement}{rad}
\nmR[R]{$R$}{Circle radius}{m}
\nmR[B]{$B_i$}{Biot number}{-}
\nmR[RF]{$\omega$}{Angular displacement}{rad}
%=====================================================
%===================Greek Symbols ====================
%=====================================================
\nmG[O]{$\omega$}{Angular velocity}{kg/s}
\nmG[A]{$\theta$}{Angular displacement}{rad}
%=====================================================
%===================Other Symbols ====================
%=====================================================
\nmO[RA]{$\theta$}{Angular displacement}{rad}
\nmO[RU]{$\theta$}{Angular displacement}{rad}
\nmO[L]{$L$}{Characteristics length}{m}
\nmO[RE]{$\theta$}{Angular displacement}{rad}

\printnomenclature[4cm]
\end{document}
```