# Can we use \glsxtrnewsymbol for a symbol containing \operatorname?

Tags: math-mode, glossaries, math-operators, glossaries-extra

Please consider the following example from [this question (Method 3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366282/181897):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols, nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]

\section{Sample}
Reference symbols: $\gls F$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$.

\end{document}
```

I've tried to define a new symbol containing `\operatorname` via `\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={foo}]{\operatorname{foo}}{\ensuremath{\operatorname{foo}}}` and received the compiler error `missing \endcsname inserted`.

Comment: Er, the second argument should be a string. With `\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={operator}]{foo}{\ensuremath{\operatorname{foo}}}` and `\gls{foo}` I get the expected output and no error.

Comment: @egreg Ah, I think I misunderstood how things work here. Am I correct that I don't use the actual symbol sequence `\operatorname{foo}`) in the article, but the sequence in the first parameter given in `\glsxtrnewsymbol` (`foo`)?

Comment: @egreg I've included the hyperref package, but the page reference in the list of symbols is not clickable, unless I also add `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}`. However, I don't want that the links are colored red. Moreover, can I remove the link in the symbol occurrence in the article to the list of symbols? I only want the link to the page in the list of symbols.

Comment: If you don't want colored links, remove the `colorlinks` option. I get working links.