# Master List of abbreviations using a .bib or .aux file

Tags: table-of-contents, bibtex, symbols, lists, acronyms

I know there are many questions about the list of symbols and abbreviations already posted but I can not find one that solves my problem directly. I found one answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366282/211159)(method 4) which relates to my question but it requires loading external files. I am using Overleaf as my tex editor so I am not entirely sure how to do that.

I am thinking of either using the `glossaries` `acro` or `nomencl` packages. I think `nomencl` is the most straightforward.

What I want:

1. To define all my symbols and/or abbreviations in a `.aux` or `.bib` master file (can be a separate file for symbols and one for abbreviations if necessary)
2. When I type in my document and use for example `\ac{NY}` the abbreviation 'NY' appears in my text and the entry is taken from the `.bib` or `.aux` file and added to the List of Abbreviations.
3. Use the code `\input{ListofSymb}` where I want the list to appear.

I do something similar with my preamble and my bibliography, whereby I have a master list that I have for all my projects and I just recall the files using `\input`.

MWE:

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
```

Main file

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}

\input{1.mypreamble}

\begin{document}

\input{ListofSymb}

This is a test paragraph where I will use some of the entries in the "ListofSymb" file. The entries I use are the only one I want to appear in the printed List of Symbols i.e. Not all symbols in the master list must appear the List of Symbols. I want symbols; $\gls{a}$, $\gls{t}$ and
$\gls{F}$ to appear. Additionally, they should appear in alphabetical order.

\end{document}
```

ListofSymb

```
@entry{x,
 name={\ensuremath{x}},
 description={position}
}
@entry{v,
 name={\ensuremath{v}},
 description={velocity}
}
@entry{a,
 name={\ensuremath{a}},
 description={acceleration}
}
@entry{t,
 name={\ensuremath{t}},
 description={time}
}
@entry{F,
 name={\ensuremath{F}},
 description={force}
}
```

Output:

[image]

I'm not sure if the packages and code used in this example is correct but its the closest I could get. I have taken examples from many different answers so it may be slightly jumbled.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "a .aux or .bib master file". Do you literally mean to write to a file such as `\jobname.aux` that gets overwritten each and every time a LaTeX file is compiled? Pleas clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure what type of file would be best to use. `.tex` might work best instead. I just want the file to be a personal database that stores all the symbols I use in my main document. Instead of having all the details of each entry in the main file, I want to have the entry details in a secondary file where i can then use `\input`

Comment: I think it's a good idea to avoid file name extensions -- such as log, aux, blg, bbl, bib, and a few others -- that have special meaning  to TeX, LaTeX, and friends. `.tex` is probably safe, though.

Comment: Okay, so using a `.tex` file, do you have any idea how i would go about this? Best packages, best syntax etc.

Comment: I want to try remove excess clutter from my source code, so I want the code for abbreviations in a separate file. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found a suitable answer. It is not exactly what I was hoping for in terms of a master list but I am happy with the results I have for now, so I am posting this answer for anyone that has the same problems.

I made use of the `standalone` package along with the `nomencl`package.

I added the following to my preamble:

```
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}

\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{\bigskip
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{\large{Symbols}}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{\large{Abbreviations}}]}{}}}
```

Then I created a `.tex` file called `abb.tex` with following code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}

\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{\bigskip
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{\large{Symbols}}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{\large{Abbreviations}}]}{}}}

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature[3cm]
\nomenclature[A]{ABAQUS/CAE}{Complete Abaqus Environment}
\nomenclature[A]{ASTM}{American Society for Testing and Materials}
\nomenclature[A]{CDM}{Continuum Damage Mechanics}
\nomenclature[A]{CLT}{Cross-Laminated Timber}
\nomenclature[A]{FRP}{Fibre Reinforced Polymer}
\nomenclature[A]{FEM}{Finite Element Modelling}
\nomenclature[A]{FEA}{Finite Element Analysis}
\nomenclature[A]{Glulam}{Glue-Laminated Timber}
\nomenclature[A]{MoR}{Modulus of Rupture}
\nomenclature[A]{MoE}{Modulus of Elasticity}
\nomenclature[A]{NDT}{Non-destructive Tests}
\nomenclature[A]{SA}{South Africa(n)}
\nomenclature[A]{UMAT}{User-defined material model}
\nomenclature[A]{USDFLD}{User-defined field}
\nomenclature[S]{$G$}{Modulus of Rigidity}
\nomenclature[S]{$I_k$}{Moment of inertia of all knots within 15cm of the critical cross section}
\nomenclature[S]{$I_g$}{Gross moment of inertia}

\end{document}
```

The `{standalone}` and `[preview]` allow the `abb.tex` file to be compiled on its own and then when using an `\input{abb}` command in the main text file the preamble of the `abb.tex` file is ignored and does not clash with the existing preamble in the main document.

Therefore my main document MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}
\input{1.mypreamble}
\begin{document}

Some text

\newpage
\input{abb}
\newpage

Some text 

\end{document}
```

[image]