# how make Symbols in Latex?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to make Symbols for my thesis. why they are in the centre and how I can put them in the left of the page?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{unbthesis}
%\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % no number for Vita in ToC
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}
\title{Outer approximations of core points for integer programming}
\author{Naghmeh Shahverdizadeh Shargh}
\predegree{Master of Science, University of Shahid Beheshti, Iran, 2013}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\gau{Mathematics and Statistics}
\supervisor{David Bremner, Ph.D, Computer Science\\ & Barry Monson, Ph.D,
Mathematics}
\examboard{Branimir Ćaćić, Ph.D, Mathematics
Chair\\  & Nicholas Touikan,  Ph.D, Mathematics}
\externalexam{name, degree,
department/field, institution}
\date{Month, 2020}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\unbtitlepage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}
\include{dedication}
\include{abstract}
\include{acknowledgments}
%%-----------Table of Contents------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
%%------------List of Tables----------------------
\listoftables{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
%%------------List of Figures----------------------

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
%%-------------change single space to double space--------
\doublespacing \pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}
\newcommand{\Po}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} 
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} 
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} 
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}} 
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
%
% 
\newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}} 

\newcommand{\vt}{\mathrm{vert}}
\newcommand{\conv}{\mathrm{conv}}
\newcommand{\Cir}{\mathrm{Cir}}
\newcommand{\Fix}{\mathrm{Fix}}
\newcommand{\spa}{\mathrm{span}}
\newcommand{\PCir}{\mathrm{PCir}}
\newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{rank}}
\newcommand{\core}{\mathrm{core}}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={all-ones vector}]{v}{\ensuremath{ \mathbf{1}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Euclidean inner product in \ensuremath{ \R^{n}}}]{g}{\ensuremath{ \langle ., . \rangle}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={convex hull of the integer point \ensuremath{z} under the group  \ensuremath{G} }]{4}{\ensuremath{\conv(G_{z})}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={convex hull of the set $S$}]{3}{\ensuremath{\conv(S)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={$G$-orbit representatives of the core set of a group $ G $}]{4}{\ensuremath{ \core/(G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of all core points of a group $ G $}]{5}{\ensuremath{ \core(G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of core points of a group $  G$ that are contained in a set $ S$}]{3}{\ensuremath{ \core(G,S)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={cyclic group of order $ n$}]{6}{\ensuremath{ C_{n} }}

\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long]
```

[image: ww]

Comment: The layout of the page very much depends on the document class that you use, as well as on the code before the symbol list. Can you please provide a *complete* small document that shows the behaviour and that we can compile ourselves?

Comment: @gernot  please see edit

Comment: Is it this link useful? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348640/how-to-effectively-use-list-of-symbols-for-a-thesis

Answer (score 1):

Enlarge the width of the description. Since the symbol table is centered, the margins will shrink.

```
\glsdescwidth=9.5cm
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long]
```

[image]

The class `unbthesis` is essentially the same as the `report` class.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

% Only needed for example
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\conv}{\mathrm{conv}}
\newcommand{\core}{\mathrm{core}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={all-ones vector}]{v}{\ensuremath{ \mathbf{1}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Euclidean inner product in \ensuremath{ \R^{n}}}]{g}{\ensuremath{ \langle ., . \rangle}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={convex hull of the integer point \ensuremath{z} under the group  \ensuremath{G} }]{G}{\ensuremath{\conv(G_{z})}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={convex hull of the set $S$}]{convS}{\ensuremath{\conv(S)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={$G$-orbit representatives of the core set of a group $ G $}]{core/G}{\ensuremath{ \core/(G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of all core points of a group $ G $}]{coreG}{\ensuremath{ \core(G)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of core points of a group $  G$ that are contained in a set $ S$}]{coreGS}{\ensuremath{ \core(G,S)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={cyclic group of order $ n$}]{Cn}{\ensuremath{ C_{n} }}

\glsdescwidth=9.5cm
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long]
\end{document}
```