# Creating a List of Symbols

Tags: symbols, listings, overleaf

I am writing a longer mathematical text, and I want to create a list of symbols.

What is the recommanded way of doing this?
I have tried to search older questions on this topic. Some seem to be outdated, or not specific enough.

You can also refer to the related CTAN article. Searching for "list of symbols" does not have any result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). What was wrong with the questions/answers you have found? You need to be more specific what you want to achieve. What is wrong with this here [for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348640/how-to-effectively-use-list-of-symbols-for-a-thesis).

Comment: @Roland I do not know anything about creating a list of symbols. When I create an index to find the vocabulary that is introduced i just write \index{something} and it is automatically created. A list of symbols seems to be more complicated, and I need a somewhat indepth description on how to create it.

Comment: What about the list from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject)?

Comment: @KevinDietrich When I understand correctly this is not what I was asking for. I asked how to create a "List of Symbols", as you see it in a mathematical text, so you can navigate through the text more easily. I do not want a list of the most common mathematical symbols as reference.