# List of Symbols and List of Abbreviations

Tags: luatex, glossaries-extra, vscode

Since all questions I could find to this matter are really old and not really helpful (please correct me if I'm wrong, I just couldn't find anything useful on this matter!) I'm starting a new question.

As the title says I want to include a List of Symbols and a List of Abbreviations in my document. For doing so I want to use the `glossaries-extra` package. Inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348640/how-to-effectively-use-list-of-symbols-for-a-thesis/366282#366282) questions answer I got a decently working example for the List of Symbols. I also have come so far to get a List of abbreviations shown in the document but unfortunately I don't knwo how to properly fill it with content.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[symbols,abbreviations,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,sort=use]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries
\glstocfalse    % don't add the glossaries to the table of contents

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\newglossaryentry{apc}{%
name={APC},%
description={antigeen-presenterende cel}%
type=abbreviations%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\printglossary[type=abbreviations,style=long,title={List of Abbreviations}]

\chapter{Symbols}
    Reference symbols: $\gls{F}$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$.
\chapter{Abbreviations}
    Here is some text, where we use \gls{apc}.

\end{document}
```

The List of Symbols is looking fine:

[image]

The List of Abbreviations reads:

[image]

The line `\printglossary[type=abbreviations,style=long,title={List of Abbreviations}]` in my editor (VSCode) is marked as faulty with the comment `Glossary` abbreviations' is missing.`and the LaTeX Compiler Output has the error message`Package glossaries-extra Warning: Glossary `abbreviations' is missing on input line 23.`

I am currently compiling with only `lualatex` -> LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)

Later i will have to use `lualatex -> biber -> lualatex`

I think my main problem is that I don't really understand how this whole package works and the package documentation is a bit too complicated for me...